# UIButton's sender.tag is always 0, despite different set values

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I take some UIButton on a storyboard，then i bind these Button with a IBAction function,but the value of `sender.tag` always 0

```swift
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    // 告诉系统等使用的时候是有值的，所以这里不需要
    var player: AVAudioPlayer!
    let sounds = ["note1", "note2", "note3", "note4", "note5", "note6", "note7"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func play(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print(sender.tag)
        play(tag: sender.tag)
    }
    
    // 封装函数
    func play(tag :Int) {
    
        // 确定文件有就加!
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: sounds[tag], withExtension: "wav")!
        do {
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            
            player.play()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

I expecting the value of the `sender.tag` will be 1-8,not always 0

Comment: Did you actually set the tags of the buttons in the storyboard? They are not automatically set by the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

By default Apple set `0` as tag to all views. If you want to set, you have to mention them in the storyboard or programmatically.

### Storyboard/ xib file

[image]

### Programmatically

```
yourView.tag = number that you want to have
```

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622493-tag)

Answer (score -3):

Yourbuttonname.tag = 1

Add this line in your code yourbutton outlets.tag and the value that you want to set

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).